# Linear Discriminant Analysis in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working on performing a LDA in Matlab and I am able to get it to successfully create a threshold for distinguishing between binary classes. However, I noticed that the threshold always crosses the origin which gives me incorrect thresholds. Is there a way to perform an LDA without a threshold crossing the origin in Matlab?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which formulation you are using for LDA. 
By threshold, I assume you're referring to decision threshold? 
In the code below the prior probabilities affect the decision threshold, so you may not be setting them correctly.

Here is some sample pseudo code:

*N = number of cases
c= number of classes
Priors = vector of prior probabilities for each case per class
Target = Target labels for each case per class
dimension of Data = Features x Cases.*

Get target labels for each data point:

```
T = Targets(:,Cases);      % Target labels for each case
```

Calculate the mean vector per class and the common covariance matrix:

```
classifier.u = [mean(Data(:,(T(1,:)==1)),2),mean_nan(Data(:,(T(2,:)==1)),2),....,mean_nan(Data(:,(T(2,:)==c)),2];   % Matrix of data means
classifier.invCV = cov(Data');
```

Get discriminant value using class mean vectors and common covariance matrix:

```
A1=classifier.u;
B1=classifier.invCV;
D = A1'*B1*Data-0.5*(A1'*B1.*A1')*ones(d,N)+log(Priors(:,Cases));
```

Function will produce c discriminant values. The case is then assigned to the class with the largest discriminant value.

Comment: I see. I am just using the classify function in Matlab currently and graphing it using gscatter. I am new to the concepts of LDA but I will look into your method. However, I think this is for classifying incoming data points correct?

What I am trying to do is to train the LDA and then graph its decision threshold to see how the data points are laid out and what the regions look like.

Comment: Well you can only graph the decision threshold if you have 3 features or less but you can do it by training the classifier using classify, then plot the training data using the discriminant function produced by training as if it were new data being classified to get the decision threshold for e.g. 2 features